# mostrar un mensaje en vez de mostrar en un gridview el resultado de la busqueda

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

soy nuevo en esto de C# y tengo este proyecto el cual me pidieron que ya no quieren mostrar los datos en una tabla , solo quieren que salga un mensaje que diga "se encuentra esa persona " y si no esta su rfc en esa base diga 'persona no se encuentra en esta área'

```
protected void btnBuscador_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string rfcTxt = txtBuscador.Text.Trim();
            rfcTxt.Length.ToString();
            string nameTxt = txtBuscador2.Text;
            CV_ver.Visible = true;

            if (rbRFC.Checked == false)
            {

            }
            else if (rfcTxt.Length < 11)
            {
                LblBus.Visible = true;
                LblBus.Text = "El campo RFC debe contener 12 ó 13 caracteres.";
                CV_ver.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
             SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionDate"].ConnectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("consultarRFC_2", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("rfc", rfcTxt);

                cmd.Parameters.Add(p1); 


                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                CV_ver.DataSource = dt;
                CV_ver.DataBind();

            }
```

Comment: un favor agrega lo que tienes en tu sp tu script y una imagen de lo que sale para poder ayudarte

Comment: @Mario `CV_ver` es su `gridview` ?

Comment: @mario espero haber ayudado.

Comment: Un mensaje en donde? tipo un messagebox?

Comment: Deberias aclara varias cosas en tu pregunta. Que es un desarrollo web. Que quieres hacer con la respuesta? Quien dispara el alert?

Comment: si ahorita edito mi pregunta, gracias @gbianchi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de la linea: `da.Fill(dt);` es tan simple como agregar esto:

```
string mensaje;

// Obtenga una referencia ClientScriptManager de la clase Página.
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    mensaje = "alert(\"La Persona se encuentra.\");";
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                                  "MENSAJE", mensaje, true);
}
else
{
    mensaje = "alert(\"La Persona no se encuentra en esta área.\");";
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                                  "MENSAJE", mensaje, true);
}
```

Debe tomar en cuenta que en todas las parte de su código donde tenga `CV_ver.Visible = true;` debe volverlo `false` para no mostrarlo o bien eliminar el código.

Ademas si no utilizará su `GridView` **no hace falta que le asigne el origen de datos**:

```
CV_ver.DataSource = dt;
CV_ver.DataBind();
```

---

Como plantea @gbianchi si solo obtendrá un único resultado `rfc` porque no usar `ExecuteScalar()`, de este modo se evita tener que usar `SqlDataAdapter` y `DataTable`.

Entonces sería algo como esto:

```
string mensaje;

// Obtenga una referencia ClientScriptManager de la clase Página.
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar())))
{
    mensaje = "alert(\"La Persona se encuentra.\");";
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                                  "MENSAJE", mensaje, true);
}
else
{
    mensaje = "alert(\"La Persona no se encuentra en esta área.\");";
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                                  "MENSAJE", mensaje, true);
}
```

> - MSDN: [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb359558(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Asi es amigo @J. Rodríguez, esto es prácticamente lo que se requiere , solo una pregunta me marca que "el nombre MessageBox no existe en el contexto actual" ,

Comment: @Mario su desarrollo es `WinForms`? esto es para windows forms ya que no especificó en su pregunta, su desarrollo es Web?

Comment: si disculpen amigos, efectivamente mi desarrollo es web

Comment: @Mario Verifique mi respuesta actualizada, y haga la prueba.

Comment: Convert va a fallar si el campo no es un valor numerico.

Comment: me manda un mensaje de que ScriptManager "no existe en el contextos actual "

Comment: @gbianchi pues para evitar eso, lo convertire en `String` y listo!

Comment: @Mario porque le falta agregar un ensamblado, si colola el mouse encima  `ScriptManager` verá que dejabo le muestra una rayita en la que le debería sugerir agregar la referencia a su pagina.

Answer (score 0):

@mario lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente.

que en tu datatable validas si hay información si sale que tu datatable no tiene datos le mandas un string o lbl o texbox que no tiene nada de información si tiene que muestre que hay  información

```
protected void btnBuscador_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string rfcTxt = txtBuscador.Text.Trim();
     rfcTxt.Length.ToString();
     string nameTxt = txtBuscador2.Text;
     CV_ver.Visible = true;

    if (rbRFC.Checked == false)
    {

    }
    else if (rfcTxt.Length < 11)
    {
         LblBus.Visible = true;
         LblBus.Text = "El campo RFC debe contener 12 ó 13 caracteres.";
         CV_ver.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionDate"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("consultarRFC_2", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("rfc", rfcTxt);

        cmd.Parameters.Add(p1); 

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        // CV_ver.DataSource = dt;
        //CV_ver.DataBind();

        if (dt .Rows.Count == 0)
        {
           string mensaje ;
           mensaje='persona no se encuentra en esta área';
        }
        else
        {
           string mensaje ;
           mensaje='se encuentra esa persona';
        }
  }
```

Comment: si CV_ver  es el gridview

Comment: Pienso que esta declaración: `string mensaje ;` debería hacerla fuera de la condición y asi no tiene que declarar la variable 2 veces, ademas debería agregar un `MessageBox` para mostrar dicho mensaje.

Comment: Porque hacer un adapter, un datatable y todo eso, si con un executescalar, puede saber si le devolvio algo o no y se ahorra todo ese lio en memoria?

Comment: @gbianchi tienes razón . tambien se podria asi y ya no consumiria memoria.